# What are trivial and non-trivial Dirichlet characters?

Tags: dirichlet-character

How to define them properly? And where to find free official documentation about it on the web please?

I've been looking around for clear definitions for more than one hour now, without success. I need precisions.

Here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character

Is the Dirichlet character of modulus $m$ the non-trivial one and the principal character a trivial one?

In advance, thanks.